# Catalog images resize command not working in Magento 2?

Tags: image-resizing, magento-2.1.7

Catalog images not resizing as per `view.xml` dimensions.

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

This command run successfully but still not resizing images.

What is the reason behind it? Can somebody help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: can you please give more info on this